# Facing issue with on click and double click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using on click ajax call for take html from a file to append To a div and then on click to remove it by class. The single click is working fine inserting and removing but when by mistake double clicking or on double clicking the html is coming duplicate. Also add it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amiralamkhan/b9omyx1g/7/)

here is my jQuery code.

```
$('.srcbx').on('click',function(){
    if($('.srcbx').hasClass('opened')){
        $("form.search").slideUp(1500,function(){$(this).remove();});
        $(".srcbx").removeClass("opened");
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/load.php",
            data:{action:'search-html'},
            success:function(data){
                $(data).appendTo("header .container").slideDown(1500,function(){$(this).show();});
                $("#search").keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val().length >= 3){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/load.php",
                        data:{action:'search',keyword:$(this).val()},
                        beforeSend:function(){
                            $("form.search").prepend("<div class='loader'></div>");
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#suggesstion").show();
                            $("#suggesstion").html(data);
                            $("form.search .loader").remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#suggesstion").hide();
                }
                });
                $("#search-btn").click(function(){
                    var v = $("#search").val(); 
                    window.location.href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/?s="+v;
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
        $('.srcbx').addClass('opened');
    }
});
```

Comment: There's probably a fancy way, but you could use `.one()` instead of `.on` so that it only happens once, or you could disable the button until ajax has completed, or just have a flag eg `if(running===true) return; running=true;` which you clear in `$.ajax().always()`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using the click for adding and removing so the ``` .one() ``` is not for this right? how can i disable or add a flag? you can add here? https://jsfiddle.net/amiralamkhan/b9omyx1g/10/

Comment: If you want to use .one() (it's not very good UX in this case without additional styling, but fixes your problem) and be able to click it again then you need to add it back using another .one() in the `.always()`

Comment: I don't like the .one() can you show me the code for disable the button or add flag? on my jsfiddle?

Comment: Had a closer look at your code and you're essentially already adding a `flag` with `$('.srcbx').addClass('opened');`.  So I'm not exactly sure *where* in your code your problem is.  I already (perhaps incorrectly) made some assumptions such as assuming "double click" meant "click twice" (which is subtly different) - but do you mean multiple keyups in #search?  It's great you've included some code, but perhaps you could reduce your code to only the relevant parts and remove anything that's not relevant.

Comment: i added simple code on jsfiddle you can take a look? https://jsfiddle.net/amiralamkhan/b9omyx1g/10/

Comment: Yes, had a look a the fiddle - it's much reduced.  You might like to try [finish](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) or [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) - I added this to your fiddle but it didn't work too well and I think it's because you're adding/removing the html rather than just showing/hiding (with slide) https://jsfiddle.net/1snrw980/

Comment: I just checked this is a good way to use stop()? I added it on code but seem it is not working well you can check the live here https://www.baqsa.pk/ click on top search icon first double click and try

Answer (score 1):

Fixed..
I just add multi flags like this and it is working fine and ignoring double clicks.

```
if(!$('.srcbx').hasClass('opened') && !$('form').hasClass('search')){}
```